# Machine Learning Features Recorded At Different Timestamps & Locations

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, feature-selection

Suppose that you are trying to model the following hypothetical situation - where each of your features is a separate time series, as is the target variable. However the feature time series occur before the target time series e.g.:

```
action (feature space X) -> elapsed time -> outcome (target Y)
```

Examples of why time lag could occur: sensor providing target variable readings is downstream of a process, etc. Does anyone know what the best approach is for linking the feature space to the target?

If this is not clear here is an examples:

Contrived example (quality of water in a river):

- Treatment applied to river water (X = [chemical concentration added to water, flow rate of water at chemical addition, etc]
- 100m Downstream quality is sample and recorded Y = water quality

Modelling Y= quality = F(treatment) = F(X)

My question is how best to incorporate features when there is a time lag between the feature and the target variable? My thinking on possible solutions is:

1. Use a physical model to bridge the time gap and link X to Y e.g. model  velocity of the river
2. Use a sequence model (e.g. LSTM) and feed however long the elapsed time is
3. Discretize the continious process and average across the sections

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more what exactly your main goal is, there seem to be a number of related but slightly distinct tasks: (i) prediction of the target from the features (supervised learning), (ii) causal analysis of a treatment effect, (iii) inference on the underlying temporal process?

Comment: Hey @mloning I have tried to make this clearer :)

Comment: I'm still not sure what your are trying to achieve. In particular, what do you mean by "_linking_ the feature space to the target"? You can always try to predict the target from the features. If you already have data, perhaps describe your dataset in more detail?